# dlclose does not call library destructors, dlopen called just once

Tags: 12.10, g++, glibc, ld, dynamic-linking

consider the following code for a dynamic loaded library built with g++-4.7 on linux, `-fPIC` and linked with `-rdynamic` option:

```
typedef std::vector< void* > cbRegister_t;

struct Wrapper
{
    cbRegister_t instance;
    Wrapper() : instance() { HDebugLog("Wrapper CTOR!");}
    ~Wrapper() { HDebugLog("Wrapper DESTRUCTOR!"); }
};
inline cbRegister_t& getLibraryUnregisterMap()
{
    static Wrapper unregisterLibraryMap;
    HDebugLog("getLibraryUnregisterMap: we have " <<unregisterLibraryMap.instance.size() << " elements. the address of the map is " << &unregisterLibraryMap.instance);
    return unregisterLibraryMap.instance;
}

void registerLibrary(void* p)
{
  auto& map = getLibraryUnregisterMap();
  map.push_back(p);
}

void unregisterLibrary()
{
  auto& map = getLibraryUnregisterMap();
}

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) library_init()
{
  static SomeData cbContainer;
  HDebugLog("Library constructor: address of static cbContainer is: " << &cbContainer );
  registerLibrary( &cbContainer);
} 
void __attribute__ ((destructor)) library_fini()
{ unregisterLibrary(); }
```

This code loads fine from a client with `dlopen` and the `RTLD_NOW` flag. The library constructor is called. The problem happens when i call `dlclose` on the handle. It gives status zero, meaning that it was successful. But the library destructor `library_fini` is not called. `dlopen` is called on a single place so the reference count should not be a problem, but in order to be absolutely sure that there are really no `references dangling` i tried doing the `dlclose` several times:

```
int result = dlclose(handle);
HDebugLog("Library::dynamicLibraryClose: closing library: " << libraryPath);
HDebugLog("Library::dynamicLibraryClose: dlclose 1 failed with error: " << result << " => " );
result = dlclose(handle);
HDebugLog("Library::dynamicLibraryClose: dlclose 2 failed with error: " << result << " => " );
result = dlclose(handle);
HDebugLog("Library::dynamicLibraryClose: dlclose 3 failed with error: " << result << " => " );
result = dlclose(handle);
HDebugLog("Library::dynamicLibraryClose: dlclose 4 failed with error: " << result << " => " );
result = dlclose(handle);
HDebugLog("Library::dynamicLibraryClose: dlclose 5 failed with error: " << result << " => " );
result = dlclose(handle);
HDebugLog("Library::dynamicLibraryClose: dlclose 6 failed with error: " << result << " => ");
result = dlclose(handle);
HDebugLog("Library::dynamicLibraryClose: dlclose 7 failed with error: " << result << " => ");
result = dlclose(handle);
HDebugLog("Library::dynamicLibraryClose: dlclose 8 failed with error: " << result << " => " );
HAssertMsg( !libraryPath.empty(), "library path is not set");
HAssertMsg( 0 == dlopen(libraryPath.c_str(), RTLD_NOLOAD) , "library is still loaded");
```

All those debug logs show that each time i call `dlclose` the status result is zero. Success!

The last assertion, which doesn't fail, confirms that the library is not resident anymore . But at this point `library_fini` has not been called yet!

This behavior is definitely a bug, either on gcc or `ld.so` (or whatever is using linux/ubuntu to dynamically load libraries these days). This behavior clearly is not what the standard says, because library destructors should be guaranteed to be run if the reference count is zero *before dlclose returns*. library destructors happen to be run after the `Wrapper.instance` is destroyed, which renders the library destructor completely useless, as is not able to do any finalization of the data

Comment: Have you considered that the fact your function: void unregisterLibrary() { auto& map = getLibraryUnregisterMap(); } do not utilize map variable anywhere, the compiler optimization effectively remove the call? I know 4.7 had some new optimizations in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with glibc 2.17, gcc 4.8.0 or icc 13.1 or icc 12.1:

`icc -std=c99 -nostdlib -shared test.c -o /tmp/test`

```
/* test.c */
#include 
#include 

int __attribute__((constructor)) x_init(void)
{
    puts("init() works");
    return 0;
}

int __attribute__((destructor)) x_fini(void)
{
    puts("fini() works");
    return 0;
}
```

against:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

int
main(void)
{
    void *foo = dlopen("/tmp/test", RTLD_LAZY);

    if (dlclose(foo) < 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also tested with glibc 2.10, glibc 2.12.  And all `RTLD_*` flags.

**Edit:**
Using an actual Ubuntu system (gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2), GNU C Library (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.15-0ubuntu20), I must say that above code works there too.  So maybe after all it's not about the compiler and/or glibc.

Comment: i suggest you to give a closer look to the documentation, just below the dlclose() section: "http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man3/dlopen.3.html "libraries    should    export    routines     using     the __attribute__((constructor))  and __attribute__((destructor)) function attributes.   See  the  gcc  info  pages  for  information  on   these, Constructor routines   are  executed  before  dlopen()  returns,  and destructor routines are executed before dlclose() returns."

Comment: That must be a GNU extension, no such thing is mentioned in POSIX.  `_fini` is a recognised special symbol though.

Comment: Also, I can confirm, it must be a bug, I tried your code with a dummy example, and it works (gcc 4.9.0, glibc 2.17)

Comment: thanks @hroptatyr, that gives me hope and strength for the road ahead (of building and installing a new gcc version)

Comment: actually, what you mean it works? that the destructor is called before dlclose returns?

Comment: Yes, both a routine tagged `__attribute__((destructor))` will be called as well as the special `_fini` routine.

Comment: I was wondering, is this a symbol mangling problem with C++?  I defined my routine as `int __attribute__((destructor)) foo(void);` and `int _fini(void)`

Comment: you shouldn't use _fini anymore, they are obsolete and dangerous. In theory just destructor and constructor attributes and you should be fine

Comment: where do you got g++ 4.9? i only see 4.8 on the gcc page. Is that some development snapshot? or you did a typo in there?

Comment: is not a mangling problem, if that were the case the destructor would not be called at all. Instead what happens is that it is called at application exit.

Comment: Yes, only that it's not portable.  The Sun compiler wants the (non-portable) `#pragma init(<your_routine>)` and `#pragma fini(<your_routine>)`, but both glibc and sun libc will accept the obsolete `_fini()`

Comment: Yes, it's the current svn snapshot.  It's definitely not a compiler problem though, I tried my code with icc 12.1 and 13.1 and they both work as advertised.

Comment: thats good enough for me, i'll upgrade to 4.8 and see how it goes. If you update your answer with this information, i'll accept the answer

Comment: I've update my whole answer now, but thorough testing shows that it must be really particular to your system and/or code.  Can you post a minimal example that shows the problem?  Even the gcc 4.7 series seems to work.